# count occurences in data set that meet (logical) conditions r

Tags: r, count, logical-operators

I want to know how I can count the number of observations containing a similar value for variable A and B in a whole data set for each observation.

The code shows what I've tried returning a 1 for variable "a" where it should return a 2 in a best case scenario and a 3 if it can not be prevented to exclude the observation it is checked for (see data set).

```
  observation A B
1           1 1 1
2           2 1 1
3           3 3 2
4           4 1 2
5           5 1 1
6           6 1 2
```

See here my try to fix it myself:

```
observation <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
A <- c(1,1,3,1,1,1)
B <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2)
dataset <- data.frame(observation, A, B)

for(i in 1:nrow(dataset)){
  if(dataset$A[i]==dataset$A[i]&dataset$B[i]==dataset$B[i])
    a <- +1
}
```

Let's take observation 1 for example. You can see in the data that the count for variable "a" should be 2. Since observation 2 and observation 5 hold a similar value for both variables; they both contain 1, just as observation 1 does.

In addition, it should not only return the desired value for "a" for observation 1, but for all observations. So the desired output is:

```
2
2
0
1
2
1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, could you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  group_by(A, B) %>% 
  mutate(count_of_similar_obs = n() - 1L)
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner in `base` R:

```
ave(dataset$observation,dataset$A,dataset$B,FUN=function(x) length(x) -1)
#[1] 2 2 0 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can do this:

```
dataset[,"tuple_occurences"] <- NA
for(i in  1:nrow(dataset)) {
  dataset[i,"tuple_occurences"] <- 
    sum(dataset$A == dataset[i,"A"] & dataset$B == dataset[i, "B"]) - 1
}
```

edit: Rewrote code because I misunderstood the question

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and the answer. Though, this is not exactly what I am looking for since I want it to run on a whole data set containing a wider variation of values. For example, if a 7th row was added containing 1 and 1 for A and B, then it would return a 2 while there are actually 3 more observations having similar values for both. Would be great if you see what I mean and could help me out :)

Comment: thank you for clearing it up, I misunderstood. Is the new answer what you were looking for?